# walk2 returns error in `match_font_c()` when rendering a R markdown

Tags: r-markdown, tidyverse

I have a R markdown in which I create some plots using ggplot and store them in a nested table.
I then want to save each plot separately saved with the name of a correspondent variable from the plot using walk2. Works fine and I can create successfully my plots, however when i try to knit the document it returns an error that I have no idea how to interpret about font. Google search as been unsuccessful and I am quite sure two days ago the code was working fine until I updated a bunch of packages.

```
my_data_to_save <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(title) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(dotplot = pmap(list(data, ontology), function(d, o){
    pp <- dotplot_results(d)
    pp + 
       labs(title = o) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12), 
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
      scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1,1))
  })
  )
```

```
walk2(my_data_to_save$dotplot, my_data_to_save$title, ~ggsave(plot = .x,filename = paste0(output_images, .y, "_dotplot.png"), width = 8, height = 8))
```

This is the error code:

```
Error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `match_font_c()`:
! bad value
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::walk2(...)
  2. purrr::map2(.x, .y, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  3. purrr:::map2_("list", .x, .y, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  7. global .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...)
  8. ggplot2::ggsave(...)
     ...
 12. base::lapply(alias_lookup()[missing_aliases], match_family)
 13. svglite (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 14. systemfonts::font_info(font, bold = bold, italic = italic)
 15. systemfonts::match_font(family, italic, bold)
 16. systemfonts:::match_font_c(family, as.logical(italic), as.logical(bold))
Execution halted
```

Google did not give me any suggestions on what could be broken. I tried to update installed packages, but nothing changed and I am without ideas on what to try.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Render multiple plots in your Markdown document using a loop? If that's the case, I think the method is different and you should use  `knitr::knit_child` inside your loop

Comment: No I am just trying to save those images in a folder when I render the markdown. They will not be rendered inside the markdown html.